# How to prevent an embedded object picture from appearing in the table of contents in Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, table-of-contents

How do I prevent an embedded object picture from appearing in the table of contents in a Word 2013?

The pictures of embedded documents (Excel and PDF) are showing up in the description line in the table of contents.  Word 2013 is assigning the icons a Heading 1 Style and will not let it be changed to any other style.
Is there a way to prevent or override the assigned style?

[image: Image in Description of TOC]

Comment: Why cannot the style of the paragraph with icon be changed? Is the field grayed out? How about copying paragraph format from another paragraph (Normal style)?

Comment: Thanks @endrju. If you select the icon the quick style menu shows Heading 1. Clicking on any other style like normal does not take.  It always reverts back to Heading 1.  I've tried inserting text on either side of the icon which can be changed to normal but the Icon always stays at Heading 1.  I've tried using an inline style separator with the same result. I haven't tried copying a style to the icon.  I'll look into that.

Comment: Try setting a style to the whole paragraph, not to the icon itself. Heading 1 is a paragraph style. Mark the whole paragraph and set a style.

Comment: @endrju Thanks for the suggestion.  I have tried setting a new paragraph style as well as was mentioned above setting the text on either side to a different style.  None of which work.  For whatever reason Word insists on assigning the Header 1 Paragraph style to the embedded document icon.

Comment: Is it possible for you to prepare a sample Word file that behaves like this and upload it?

Comment: Thanks @endrju. Your question led to my discovering the solution.  When I was trying to build an example document to illustrate the problem it didn't replicate.  This led me to discover that the final section of the Word document (where the embedded document was located) was corrupted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final section of the Word document was corrupted.

Once the section was deleted and then added back in the problem went away and the icon no longer showed up in the table of contents. Plus the standard style formatting could then be applied.

Thanks to endrju for the assistance in troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this and found an alternative solution.  Right click on the image stuck in "Heading 1" format and select Edit Picture.  This threw my picture into a different format that was not stuck in Heading 1 format, which means it no longer appears in my table of contents.  From there, I changed the picture layout so it wasn't inserted over top of the text and I was good to go.